# Access facebook login for website locally

Tags: facebook, testing, web

I am working on a website in which a user logs on using their Facebook account.  I set this up and everything going through Facebook's steps and it works great.  I have it right now to where they must be logged into an account in order to view any of the pages on the site.  While the site is live everything works exactly like it is supposed to.

My problem is that when I am just trying to edit the site and make changes to it I still have to login to view any of the pages other than the login.  I am running it on a local JBoss server for testing and when I go to see changes that I make I can't because I am not able to login to Facebook.  I get this error when trying to login:

An error occurred. Please try again later.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to set it up to where even when running locally I would still be able to view the changes that I made by signing in with a Facebook account.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working on a local testing version, best to make a separate app for development and have the URL in the application settings point locally.

For example say you have an app called "Example" create a new new app called "Example - Dev" with the same settings as "Example" but using the local URL. Now when you push changes to production ensure that the "Example" appId and secret are pushed and not "Example - Dev"

Comment: Good answer. I do this too.  I have three app ids for each app I do: one for local, one for the QA test environment, and one for production.